# Accessing downloads files on Android 11 returns no files

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, file

So, I am trying to read the files from the shared Download folder on my Android 11 device, using the file class(in Kotlin):

```
val downloads = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download")
```

But when I call the .list() function to see all the subdirectories and files, only the subdirs appear: "downloaded_rom", "Filemail", "downloaded_apex"...
I know MediaStore won't work for this purpose, and the SAF prompts the user to choose a directory, but that would be a headache for him and for me, too..
So is there a way to achieve what I need??

Comment: You do it right. You will see all the files written there by your app. Not files of other apps on Android 11+ devices

Comment: I need all the files.. The user might have downloaded some files and I need them

Comment: What has your app to do with files downloaded by other apps? But you dont have to answer. I see that you know what to do now.

Comment: There are lots of apps doing this in C++ so there must be a way in Kotlin too..

Comment: It does not depend on programming language at all.

Comment: Do you know something about Scoped storage permissions?